# How to manage CSV for add more fields for import process

Tags: php, csv, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make CSV structure to import data to database using PHP.

I have title body and a field collection like:
Friends:

name, email,number.

Friend fields is multiple.
For example:

```
firstname, firsttest@test.com, 12225435
 secondname, secondtest@test.com, 122234534
```

For title and body, i can manage easily but how can i manage for friends column in CSV.

Thanks

Comment: How many friends are you expecting there to be?

Comment: Are you intending them to be in the same table or a related table?

Comment: Friend will be infinite. I am string these data in separate tables. and one more thing i have 3-4 field collection like friends.

Comment: We can't use any separator because we can insert anything.

Comment: You may have to do this in 2 passes. Surely you cannot create a friend link until the frieded person exists as a user. So Pass1: Load all People Pass2: load the friend links

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json string to store the friends column. For example, in the csv convert friends column values as 
{"firstname":test,"email":firsttest@test.com,"number":12225435} this will now be a separate column and store it in database in a text column. While retrieving the data you can decode the json to array.

For converting the friends column to json you can copy the csv data to excel sheet and apply the formula to convert friends column json and again save the excel as csv.